# worker keeps getting temp banned with sgminer

Tags: bitcoind, cgminer

I have 3 R9 280x sapphires I use with sgminer

On almost every single pool, with or without --no-submit-stale, after about 5 min of hashing, my worker get's banned and hashing drops to zero. If I lower the intensity, I barely get 500mh/s if that. If I set it to 13, it runs normal, but I get banned?

```
sgminer -o stratum+tcp://neo.cryptcoins.net:3331 -u user.worker -p x -I 13 -D -P --no-submit-stale
```

How can I prevent from getting banned with a decent hash rate?

```
[18:58:33] RECVD: , "Worker is temporarily banned", null], "id": 666, "result":
```

Comment: Here's a mention of banning I found looking through the stratum-miner source code. `Excessive sending of invalid shares or shares above indicated target (see Stratum mining docs for set_target()) may lead to temporary or permanent ban of user,worker or IP address.`. Maybe your config settings are wrong?

Comment: @Jacob Torba That sounds correct. But I have no idea where to begin looking. sgminer doesn't have a .conf  :(

Comment: Look for error messages in output?

Comment: @Jacob Torba  Just this, and nothing else, in any log file.  [18:58:33] RECVD: , "Worker is temporarily banned", null], "id": 666, "result":
null}
JSON decode failed(1): end of file expected near ','

Comment: @dooode Post your issue here - https://github.com/veox/sgminer/issues?milestone=2&state=open

Comment: @Jacob Torba I posted there and they blamed the pool. I have since built a second miner using non sapphire r9 290 and on a different ASUS board but exact same settings and they don't get banned and I crank them up. It's got to be a hardware or driver conflict, but I see nothing in the logs.